# C programming - K&R example 1.5.2 - modified program not functioning as intended

Tags: c, increment, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

My question is simply "Why does my code on line 10 and 11 not function properly?" The intended purpose of my code is to do exactly as the original K&R code intended, but to NOT count nc whenever (getchar() == '\n') will you please enlighten me?

slightly modified K&R code:

```
/** K&R - 1.5.2 Character Counting **/
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main(){
  long nc;

  nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF){
    if (getchar() != '\n'){
      ++nc;
    }
  }
  printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

*I use 64-bit Windows 7, CodeBlocks10.05, GNU GCC Compiler.*

my current progress and understanding:

on a sample run, i type in the word `two` and hit enter, which equals 4 inputs, after which i press ctrl+Z to enter in a `^Z` or EOF character. The program then prints `1`. I was expecting it to print `3`. I suppose the only logical explanation is that it is doing exactly the opposite of what I intended (it *only* counts newline characters?). As it turns out, if I type in the word `two` and press enter, lets say 4 times, it prints `4`. It seems to be counting `nc` for every newline character entered, but yet if I press enter alone (in this case 4 times) and then EOF, it always prints `0`. Upon further experimentation, by some hand unseen 4 is perhaps a magical number for this program. If I start it up and hit enter key exactly (a number divisible by 4) times and then EOF it prints `0`. However if i hit enter some other number of times the EOF does nothing, and I must enter in `^Z` two rows, one after the other, to end the while loop correctly, and it prints `1`. This is boggling my mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble is that you need to save the value from `getchar()` – in an `int` – because you are reading two characters for each time you increment the count.  One of those is in the EOF test; the second is in the newline test.

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c != '\n')
        ++nc;
}
```

---

The reason you need to store the result of `getchar()` in an `int` and not a `char` is that it can return every possible `char` value and also a distinct value, EOF.  If you don't use `int` (you store direct into a `char`), one of two things will happen:

1. If `char` is a signed type, a legitimate character (often y-umlaut, ÿ, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, U+00FF — at least in codesets derived from Latin 1 or ISO 8859-1) will be interpreted as equivalent to EOF, and your program will terminate prematurely.
2. If `char` is an unsigned type, no character will ever be equivalent to EOF, so the program will never stop the loop.

Neither of these circumstances is desirable.  Storing the return value of `getchar()` in an `int` prevents both problems; it is the 'only' (or, at least, the simplest) correct way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, you are calling `getchar()` two times, so you're consuming two characters in each iteration.

You should understand that calling `getchar()` read a character from the input stream. If you want to test for a newline, you should store that character in a variable, and then test that variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
int c;

[...]

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n') {
      ++nc;
    }
}
```

Each time you call `getchar()` you are consuming a character from `stdin`.

Comment: You should probably explain why your solution is correct, just a little bit.

Comment: wow i just got done writing exactly that except i made c a char variable, and it does the same thing as the original K&R code?

Comment: @pyingSaucepan `char` is not wide enough to hold `EOF`, which is precisely why `getchar` returns an `int`.

Comment: when i enter type in "two" and hit enter and EOF, it still returns 4

Comment: my apologies, i forgot to put parenthesis around c = getchar()