# fgetc returns an unknown character

Tags: c, stdio

I have the following code:

```
FILE *f = fopen('/path/to/some/file', 'rb');
char c;
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
{
    printf("next char: '%c', '%d'", c, c);
}
```

For some reason, when printing out the characters, at the end of the file, an un-renderable character gets printed out, along with the ASCII ordinal -1.

```
next char: '?', '-1'
```

What character is this supposed to be? I know it's not EOF because there's a check for that, and quickly after the character is printed, the program SEGFAULT.

Comment: FYI: You should make sure that `fopen` doesn't return NULL, indicating failure.

Comment: This could be closed as a duplicate of either [`while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)` loop won't stop executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694394/) or [C programming - K&R example 1.5.2 - modified program not functioning as intended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116864/) or a dozen other similar answers I've made, not to mention those made by others on the same topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trouble is that `fgetc()` and its relatives return an `int`, not a `char`:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
>   next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).
>
> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-
>   file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.

It has to return every possible valid character value and a distinct value, `EOF` (which is negative, and usually but not necessarily `-1`).

When you read the value into a `char` instead of an `int`, one of two undesirable things happens:

- If plain `char` is unsigned, then you never get a value equal to EOF, so the loop never terminates.
- If plain `char` is signed, then you can mistake a legitimate character, 0xFF (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is treated the same as EOF, so you detect EOF prematurely.

Either way, it is not good.

#### The Fix

The fix is to use `int c;` instead of <s>`char c;`</s>.

---

Incidentally, the `fopen()` call should not compile:

```
FILE *f = fopen('/path/to/some/file', 'rb');
```

should be:

```
FILE *f = fopen("/path/to/some/file", "rb");
```

Always check the result of `fopen()`; of all the I/O functions, it is more prone to failure than almost any other (not through its own fault, but because the user or programmer makes a mistake with the file name).

Comment: Upon  successful  completion  fopen() returns a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.     Use the following for error checking in fopen :    if((fp=fopen("mat", "rb"))==NULL)
{
printf("Cannot open file.\n");
return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

This is the culprit:

```
char c;
```

Please change it to:

```
int c;
```

The return type of `fgetc` is `int`, not `char`. You get strange behavior when you convert `int` to `char` in some platforms.

Comment: I presume what is happening is that since `char` is sometimes unsigned, unlike other data types, -1 (a common `EOF` value) is implicitly cast to 255.  When then again cast to `int` to compare to `EOF`, it stays 255, and thus doesn't equal -1.