# implementing copy command using file my code is copying garbage?

Tags: c, file

Implementing copy command using file my code is copying garbage.please help me to fix

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    fp=fopen("source","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
            printf("no file\n");
            return;
    }
    else
    {
            printf("file is present\n");
            fp1=fopen("dest","w");
            while(ch=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
            fputc(ch,fp1); // why source contain is not copyed to dest?
    }
             fclose(fp);
             fclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: Hint: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: You might want to read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), and then look again at your loop condition.

Comment: Also, the return type of `fgetc` is `int`. You should change `char ch;` to `int ch;`.

Comment: @RSahu upon success it return chararcter after converting it to an int without sign extension.Upon failure or end of file or error it return EOF ie -1

Comment: @carrercarrer, if you are not convinced that `int ch;` is the right thing to do, please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/23331786/434551.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(ch=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
```

is eqivalent to:

```
while(ch = (fgetc(fp)!=EOF))
```

thus gives `ch` values either `1` or `0` depending on whether `fgetc(fp)!=EOF)` is true. What you want is:

```
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```